# Istio1.9 integration with virtual machine (aws ec2) getting host file as empty

Tags: istio, istio-sidecar, istio-gateway

I have installed mysql in a VM and wanted my EKS with istio 1.9 installed to talk with them, i am following this https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/virtual-machine/ but when am doing this step the host file which getting generated is empty file.
With this empty host file i tried but when starting the vm with this command am getting

```
> sudo systemctl start istio
```

when tailed this file

```
*/var/log/istio/istio.log*



   2021-03-22T18:44:02.332421Z     info    Proxy role      ips=[10.8.1.179 fe80::dc:36ff:fed3:9eea] type=sidecar id=ip-10-8-1-179.vm domain=vm.svc.cluster.local
2021-03-22T18:44:02.332429Z     info    JWT policy is third-party-jwt
2021-03-22T18:44:02.332438Z     info    Pilot SAN: [istiod.istio-system.svc]
2021-03-22T18:44:02.332443Z     info    CA Endpoint istiod.istio-system.svc:15012, provider Citadel
2021-03-22T18:44:02.332997Z     info    Using CA istiod.istio-system.svc:15012 cert with certs: /etc/certs/root-cert.pem
2021-03-22T18:44:02.333093Z     info    citadelclient   Citadel client using custom root cert: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2021-03-22T18:44:02.410934Z     info    ads     All caches have been synced up in 82.7974ms, marking server ready
2021-03-22T18:44:02.411247Z     info    sds     SDS server for workload certificates started, listening on "./etc/istio/proxy/SDS"
2021-03-22T18:44:02.424855Z     info    sds     Start SDS grpc server
2021-03-22T18:44:02.425044Z     info    xdsproxy        Initializing with upstream address "istiod.istio-system.svc:15012" and cluster "Kubernetes"
2021-03-22T18:44:02.425341Z     info    Starting proxy agent
2021-03-22T18:44:02.425483Z     info    dns     Starting local udp DNS server at localhost:15053
2021-03-22T18:44:02.427627Z     info    dns     Starting local tcp DNS server at localhost:15053
2021-03-22T18:44:02.427683Z     info    Opening status port 15020
2021-03-22T18:44:02.432407Z     info    Received new config, creating new Envoy epoch 0
2021-03-22T18:44:02.433999Z     info    Epoch 0 starting
2021-03-22T18:44:02.690764Z     warn    ca      ca request failed, starting attempt 1 in 91.93939ms
2021-03-22T18:44:02.693579Z     info    Envoy command: [-c etc/istio/proxy/envoy-rev0.json --restart-epoch 0 --drain-time-s 45 --parent-shutdown-time-s 60 --service-cluster istio-proxy --service-node sidecar~10.8.1.179~ip-10-8-1-179.vm~vm.svc.cluster.local --local-address-ip-version v4 --bootstrap-version 3 --log-format %Y-%m-%dT%T.%fZ       %l      envoy %n        %v -l warning --component-log-level misc:error --concurrency 2]
2021-03-22T18:44:02.782817Z     warn    ca      ca request failed, starting attempt 2 in 195.226287ms
2021-03-22T18:44:02.978344Z     warn    ca      ca request failed, starting attempt 3 in 414.326774ms
2021-03-22T18:44:03.392946Z     warn    ca      ca request failed, starting attempt 4 in 857.998629ms
2021-03-22T18:44:04.251227Z     warn    sds     failed to warm certificate: failed to generate workload certificate: create certificate: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup istiod.istio-system.svc on 10.8.0.2:53: no such host"
2021-03-22T18:44:04.849207Z     warn    ca      ca request failed, starting attempt 1 in 91.182413ms
2021-03-22T18:44:04.940652Z     warn    ca      ca request failed, starting attempt 2 in 207.680983ms
2021-03-22T18:44:05.148598Z     warn    ca      ca request failed, starting attempt 3 in 384.121814ms
2021-03-22T18:44:05.533019Z     warn    ca      ca request failed, starting attempt 4 in 787.704352ms
2021-03-22T18:44:06.321042Z     warn    sds     failed to warm certificate: failed to generate workload certificate: create certificate: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup istiod.istio-system.svc on 10.8.0.2:53: no such host"
```

Comment: team any help would be greatly appreciated  as am stuck from last night

Comment: Have you verified if the 3rd party token are enabled: `Before proceeding to generate the istio-token, as part of istioctl x workload entry, you should verify third party tokens are enabled in your cluster by following the steps describe here`. This is the part which generates the files including the hosts.

Comment: Yes, i can see it is enabled, i followed all the steps which mentioned in the istio 1.9 but no where reached!

Comment: hi any help pls

Comment: Is it like we need to add the EKS API endpoint with istiod.istio.svc